# HTML5 header tag overlaps the contents below it

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

```css
header{
    width:100%;
    background-color: #607D8B; 
    color:#8BC34A; 
    font-size:200%;
    padding: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

.image{
    width: 100%;
}

body {

height: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 name">Aayushi </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 about">About</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 experience">Experience</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 contact">Contact</div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 row div2">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 image-div">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" class="image col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    </div>
</div>
```

I am implementing a basic header whose position I am specifying as position:absolute then it overlaps the content below it.

Why does this happen? Even if I add the class navbar-fixed-top to my header then it overlaps the content below!

If I want to fix my header then what should I do? The codepen link is https://codepen.io/asinha/pen/MJZooj

```
<header>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 name">Aayushi </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 about">About</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 experience">Experience</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 contact">Contact</div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 row div2">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 image-div">
    <img src="image.jpg" class="image col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    </div>
</div>

header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index:10;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #607D8B; 
    height:10vh;
    color:#8BC34A; 
    font-size:200%;
    padding-top: 0.3em;

}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

.image{
    width: 100%;
}

.div2{
    margin-top:14%;
}
```

Comment: it would be cool if added to the CSS in your question the `navbar-fixed-top` class

Comment: Read this page and you will understand: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: And maybe this one: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: you should certainly clarify your question. try to be more specific.

Comment: edited! @Anthony

Comment: @aayushi it's hard to tell without a demo to work with, but i'm assuming the issue is because the header's content/children end up overflowing the header's height.

Comment: @aayushi i've edited my answer

Comment: I have added a snippet. You see how the header overlaps the image after getting fixed. I want  a fixed header at the top of my screen which should not overlap any of the contents. How should I do that? @Anthony

Comment: @aayushi create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and share that please...

Comment: i aleady did! @Anthony please check above

Comment: @aayushi also, to clarify: so you never want your header to overlap your `div2` but you also want `header` always fixed at the top of the page?

Comment: @aayushi that's not a jsfiddle, that's inline...

Comment: yes @Anthony I want a way to do this without using margin-top on the div2 because for many webpages the ui shows absurd disorientation when margin-top is used

Comment: can you please go to the codepen link It has the whole code @Anthony

Answer (score 2):

That's because contents positioned absolutely or fixed don't affect any other element on the page.

Switch your css to this and it looks better IMO

```
header{
    width:100%;
    background-color: #607D8B; 
    color:#8BC34A; 
    font-size:200%;
    padding: 15px;
    postion: fixed;
    z-index: 999;

}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

.image{
    width: 100%;
}

.div2{
    margin-top:14%;
}
```

I removed the headers height and position property. No need to fix something to the top of the page which will already go there by default. And the height property caused it to not fully contain its contents. If you are going to give it a height, probably better to used `min-height` in this case so it can stretch with its content.

The text inside could be raised or lowered with `line-height`, but I just used `padding` to more easily center it.

Comment: But I want to fix my header, this way it wont get fixed

Comment: This doesn't produce the behavior you want? The header contains the content inside of it now and is separate from the content below it

Comment: or by fix you mean fix it to the top of the screen as you scroll?

Comment: actually i want it to be fixed to the top of my screen. that is why I am trying to position it.Can you please help?

Comment: I updated the css in my answer, just adding "position: fixed" to the header code I posted earlier should work. I'm also assuming you're using bootstrap. You could also copy paste the navbar from this example https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/ and modify it for your needs. I'd suggest thinking about that because it'd be more mobile responsive without having to do anything

Comment: I have added a snippet. You see how the header overlaps the image after getting fixed. I want  a fixed header at the top of my screen which should not overlap any of the contents. How should I do that?

Comment: If you have something in a fixed position, and you scroll, by definition it goes on top of the non fixed content as you scroll

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146704/discussion-between-aayushi-and-ceckenrode).

Answer (score 1):

This happens because when you give an element a position of `fixed`, that element is then positioned relative to the browser window; and when you give an element a position of `absolute`, that element is then positioned relative to the nearest parent without `position: static` (which I believe is the "default" position value for elements in most browsers).

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

It's hard to know exactly why without a demo to work with, but i'm assuming the issue is because the header's content/children end up overflowing the header's height. Even though you've given your header a fixed height of `10vh`, if one resizes the browser whereby the header's `width` gets smaller, eventually a `height: 10vh` might not be tall enough to contain all of header's content, thus it overflows. To test this and find out if the content is overflowing the header, you can apply a border to header and mess around with it.

An incredibly simple solution so that your header doesn't overlap your the websites content would be to move the header lower in the z-index by applying `header { z-index: -1; }` or `.div2 { z-index: 1 }`. But I imagine this isn't what you're looking for.

**In your codepen, the reason your header is overlapping `div2` is because -- as I had already stated -- the `height` of the `header` is increasing to accomodate its overflowing content since you haven't applied a `height` to `header`.**

What you can do is apply a fixed `height` to `header` and apply these properties and values to `div2`: `position: absolute` and `top: the height of the header VH`.

https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/EXgOBp?editors=1100

As you scroll down the page, the image will, again, end up being hidden by the header; but you can't avoid this unless you fix the image too... If you don't care if the image floats over the header, then do the z-index thing which i talked about above.

If none of this is what you're looking to do. I'm sorry but I won't be able to help you until you figure out exactly what it is that you want to do. I've wasted enough time trying to figure out what you want to do.

Comment: if i do position:fixed, then also the same thing happens

Comment: @aayushi i know `position: fixed` behaves similarly to `position: absolute`--that's precisely what i explained...

Comment: I have added a snippet. You see how the header overlaps the image after getting fixed. I want  a fixed header at the top of my screen which should not overlap any of the contents. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the 'overlap' problem you have is from the links contained within the header, which overlap due to the fact that you have assigned a `height` of `10vh` to your header. `vh` is a unit relative to viewport height, and adjusts according to the screen.

Simply removing your `height` declaration will fix this problem, and allow your header to automatically expand to the height of the elements contained within.

I've created a Bootply showcasing this [**here**](https://www.bootply.com/R0z0QDSCDD).

Alternatively, you could shrink the size of the font, which have a `font-size` of `200%`.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: even with this, the header is not fixed!

Comment: Can you please clearly state exactly what "*not fixed*" means? The text is contained within the header in my Bootply. Please let me know exactly what you are trying to achieve, and why my example doesn't provide this, showcasing what is wrong in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have added a snippet. You see how the header overlaps the image after getting fixed. I want  a fixed header at the top of my screen which should not overlap any of the contents. How should I do that?